# How to allow iPhone auto-lock while playing a video

Tags: iphone, ios, video, sdk, avplayer

How can I allow iOS device to dim screen and auto-lock the device while playing a video with AVFoundation. Playing a video with AVPlayer disable screen auto-lock by default. Is there anyway to re-enable it without pausing the video play.

Comment: when you say auto lock do you mean that its locks the iPhone and goes to the lock screen?

Comment: Haven't been able to do it myself and I still don't know if there is a way to do it. 

Just as a comment...

After you pause the `AVPlayer`, the auto-lock duration starts counting down. When it expires, the device goes to sleep mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760826/allow-auto-lock-while-video-is-being-played

Comment: See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38018555/1017340

Answer (score 1):

why you want screen to go idle while playing video? The real answer is it can't be done. Following are just work arounds with serious downsides.

The only method apple allows us to use is

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled
```

You can dim screen programmatically by using a UIView with color black and slowly changing it alpha property to create the illusion of screen going idle.

Comment: "You can dim screen programmatically by using a UIView with color black" - seriously? It will not prevent battery drain.

Comment: This API will not work with AVPlayer, this answer is wrong. The real answer is it can't be done

Answer (score 0):

I worked on the application where we used AVPlayer to display video backgrounds in application. Our solution was to stop video after some idle time. I mean implementing idle timer on our side. And then send message to all background players to stop them. It's the only good workaround I know.