# Is it possible to set AVPlayer to allow the device to go to sleep during video playback?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I am working on an application that involves using AVPlayer to have a video in the background of an interface.

We've found that while video is playing, the app will never go to sleep. Is there a way to tell AVPlayer to allow the app to go to sleep regardless?

Comment: Haven't been able to do it myself and I still don't know if there is a way to do it. 

Just as a comment...

After you pause the `AVPlayer`, the auto-lock duration starts counting down. When it expires, the device goes to sleep mode.

Comment: This seems like the same question as:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267776/how-to-allow-iphone-auto-lock-while-playing-a-video

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760826/allow-auto-lock-while-video-is-being-played

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38018555/1017340

Answer (score 2):

Set `preventsDisplaySleepDuringVideo` to `false` or `NO` on the `AVPlayer` instance.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/2990522-preventsdisplaysleepduringvideop